# Register Property Group in existing type

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Is it possible to register a PropertyGroup in an existing type like bpy.types.Light ?

This doesn't work: `bpy.types.Light = PointerProperty(type=light.MyPropertyGroup)`

But this works fine if I add my addon class: `bpy.types.Light.myaddon = PointerProperty(type=light.MyPropertyGroup)`

I manage to register a single property with:
`bpy.types.Light.myproperty = FloatProperty(.......)` but this isn't really clean to add all my properties in the register function.

The reason I would like to add my properties directly into the Light type is because I have get/set functions for my properties that would need to refer to the correct self.

Thanks!

Comment: If your property group is registered akin to `bpy.types.Light.myaddon = PointerProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup)` then in an update `self` is the pointer `light.myaddon` and `self.id_data` is the light.

Comment: `self.id_data` works like a charm!
Thanks batFINGER for your amazing support on StackExchange.